# Merge several topology errors to largest in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, merge, topology

I searched first and found people who have come across a similar problem, however, they were trying to solve the errors by creating new features, and the solutions given where aimed at creating, so I'm posting my specific problem here hoping you can point me in the right direction:

I was given a shapefile with land use data but it was made by combining information from three different sources and it has some overlapping polygons.

I exported the layer to a geodatabase to run a topology check, and found over 2000 errors for the rule 'Must not overlap'.

If I select just one error, I can choose 'Merge to largest' which is what I would like to do for every error. But the merge option appears grayed out when I try to select more than one error at the same time.

[image: Can't merge multiple topology errors to largest]

Is there a tool I can use to solve all those errors at once? If it were just a few errors I'd have no problem going one by one, but there's a lot and I'm hoping there's a quicker way to deal with them.

Comment: Hi! I apologise for the rude start. I typed "Hello, everyone" at the beggining of my post but it got deleted when I hit post.

Comment: Cultural norms aren't. Greetings (and thanks) are considered rude here. See the [Tour] to better understand our "No chit-chat" guideline (which that intro paragraph just skirts under).

Comment: @Vince oops, didn't know about that. Thanks for the clarification! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Any solution here? I ran into the exact same issue - have over 5000 errors to resolve and want to batch the {Merge} option under fix with "merge into largest" for all...